# Pseudo element contained at top of parent div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-position, pseudo-element

I am currently developing a wordpress website with a Theme and I am using a Slider element from that theme but I want to add to each of the images in the slider, an `:after` element that just adds some color above the image.

My problem is that my element is not displaying outside the parent element right now and I cannot figure out why. I have tried position fixed, absolute, static, and relative, but none of those seem to work. I cannot reveal the website since it is private right now but here is a sample:

**Situation**

[image: Situation]

**Parent Div**

[image: Parent Div]

I want to add those green rectangles but they are contained by the div.

**MY CSS:**

```
.img-box:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 70px!important;
    height: 70px!important;
    background-color: green;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -20%;
    margin-top: -20%;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: _"My problem is that my element is not displaying outside the parent element right now and I cannot figure out why."_ - because it has `overflow: hidden`, according to your inspector screenshot. (Which is btw. not how you should present a problem here to begin with - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: you are totally right and thank you for taking your time, I know that is not how I should post my code in here but I was constrained by what I was allowed to show and this was the easiest way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your screenshot, your `.img-box` element has a position property set to `static`. Static-positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties, so my advice is to use position `relative`. Also, make sure that `.img-box` and all parent elements of `.img-box` element e.g. `.single-team-style-two`, and parent "container" element of `.single-team-style-two` has `overflow-x` property set to `visible`.

Comment: I tested what you have said right now, and thank you, that solved my problem but now my carousel is expanded on the whole page and I need to find a way to solve that

Comment: If the answer by kozel fixed your original question, make sure to select it as the chosen answer. :) @VSdev

Comment: @VSdev I'm glad to hear it helped you. Regarding new problem, please share a screenshot or snippet + CSS of what you have done, so I have a better understanding of what's happening